# LinearModelFit gives bad fit for simple data set

Tags: fitting

I want to fit the rather simple data set:

```
dat={{28.56, 248.35}, {28.8, 246.9}, {29.04, 247.32}, {29.28, 
      247.84}, {29.52, 246.05}, {29.76, 246.65}, {30., 248.24}, {30.24, 
      245.93}, {30.48, 249.39}, {30.72, 246.7}, {30.96, 249.37}, {31.2, 
      246.82}, {31.44, 245.98}, {31.68, 247.22}, {31.92, 246.3}, {32.16, 
      245.86}, {32.4, 248.71}, {34.8, 141.43}, {35.28, 247.31}, {36., 
      248.97}, {36.72, 248.05}, {37.44, 248.4}, {38.4, 248.39}, {39.12, 
      246.75}, {39.84, 245.64}, {40.8, 245.16}, {41.52, 247.22}, {42.24, 
      247.38}, {43.2, 247.}, {43.92, 246.71}, {44.64, 247.75}, {45.6, 
      247.08}, {48., 247.14}}
```

with a line of best fit. The first $17$ pairs of numbers are equidistant regarding their x-position, the last $16$ pairs are not. I used `LinearModelFit[]`, but it gave me a bad fit and I don't understand why.

```
fit = LinearModelFit[dat, x, x] 
Show[ListPlot[dat, PlotRange -> {{26, 50}, {242, 250}}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {26, 243}], Plot[fit[x], {x, 28, 50}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Try this: `ListPlot[dat, PlotRange -> All]`.  It will give you the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you :)

Comment: I was staring at this for a good 5 minutes before it occurred to me to do that :)  The default `PlotRange` setting might cut off outliers.  `PlotRange -> All` should show everything.

Comment: I'll keep that tip in mind :)

Comment: This is what I usually do to get that kind of problems `fit = LinearModelFit[dat, x, x];
Show[ListLinePlot[dat, PlotRange -> Full], Plot[fit[x], {x, 1, 50}]]`